# Changing the order of columns in QGIS attribute table?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

How can I rearrange the order of columns in my attribute table?  I'm inputting a lot of data and would prefer to not have to scroll all the way to the end of my columns for each new entry.  Ideally i'd like to be able to just filter out the columns i don't need to view for this task.

Comment: I found the answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167493/rearranging-display-order-of-attribute-table-fields-using-qgis).  See Dan's answer.  I'll leave this question in case it helps someone else.

Comment: In QGIS 3.x, you can use Refactor Field algorithm from the Pocessing panel (~equivalent to Table manager with QGIS 2.x)

Comment: You can *hide* columns without rearranging them. Right click on any column header > Organize columns > unselect the columns you want to hide.